# How to achieve authentication using an XML users file in grails?

Tags: grails, restful-authentication, grails-validation

Being a newbie to grails, I want to learn how to authenticate users using an XML users file? For ex: A user is able to login only when the credentials(username & password) match with the one in XML file. Can anyone please help giving a simple example. I basically want to know what additonal classes are to be written or require modifications. Please guide!!!

Comment: I guess(from your tag) that you want to do restful validation, which means the request & response are xml files. But I don't know how it relates to the scenario you describe. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: For my app, the user info is stored in xml file against which the user authentication occurs. may be matching some key value pair..

Comment: I'm afraid that you may need to do the authentication part yourself (reading the xml file, and compare password). I know no plugin supporting this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring Security Core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) has pluggable support for the source of user authentication data. Neither the plugin nor Spring Security care where you get the data, just that you implement the required interface so the other classes can use it.

All you'd need to do is create a `UserDetailsService` implementation that parses the XML and creates a `GrailsUser` instance from there. See section "11 Custom UserDetailsService" in [the documentation](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/) for an example customized class and description of how to wire things up.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to authenticate against a xml file containing user information? the easiest and quickest way would be to integration spring security by using the grails plugin http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core. the user is stored in the database and you can configure lots of things like crypto, acls, ...

Comment: at the point of authentication read the xml file and try to find the right node. there are some classes for reading xml files http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html. i think there is no built-in functionality for xml authentication.

Comment: Spring Security Core plugin is a great tool for implementing authentication in grails apps. I believe there is a mechanism which you can use to customize authentication process ;)